# ROS Answers SE migration: Qt Libraries?

Tags: cmake, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to use the QString library in my code. I am not making a GUI, I just want to use some of the Qt libraries... Can anyone help me with this? Here is my solution in the CMakeLists.txt file [not working]:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
rosbuild_add_executable(laser_test src/laser_test.cc)
```

Thanks,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31035/qt-libraries?/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to tell cmake where the Qt headers are and link against the Qt libraries you need.  This site is helpful:

http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects

You will need to do something like this:

```
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
```

And:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(laser_test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

After the `find_package` call.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5